# Tempo de Mudança do CSS com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, transição

Tenho uma função:

```
function togglePopup1() {
    document.getElementById('desktop-card').style.width = '480px';
}
```

O código é para que o `width` da página aumente com um clique.

Mas como faço pra essa mudança acontecer, por exemplo, em 2 segundos? Já procurei em todos os lugares e não achei como inserir um tempo de execução.

Além de `width`, há várias outras propriedades do CSS que também são alteradas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Como assim acontecer em 2 segundos? Demorar 2 segundos para disparar o evento ou a duração da animação ser de 2 segundos ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu não sou muito bom em javascript mas a solução e simples e da para ser feita com CSS utilizando [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

```js
function togglePopup1() {
    document.getElementById('desktop-card').style.width = '480px';
}
```

```css
#desktop-card {
  width: 100px; /* tamanho inicial */
  height: 50px; 
  background: #ddd; /* Cor para demonstrar o efeito  */
  transition: 2s; /* Class transition */
  -moz-transition: 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: 2s; /* Opera */
}
```

```html
<button onclick="togglePopup1()">Start</button>
<div id="desktop-card"><div>
```

Comment: Vitor, vllw mano. Consegui aqui, na madruga tava com tanto sono que nem lembrei que poderia usar com CSS. Porém, não funcionou para por exemplo "document.getElementById('desktop-card').style.display = 'block';". No caso da Div #desktop-card aparecer suave também.

Answer (score 5):

Partindo do princípio em que você tem a classe de estilo pronta para o `desktop-card`, basta você adicionar as propriedades `transition` nessa classe e quando mudar o estilo no **JS** ele irá receber a transição de acordo com o que você configurar:

```js
function togglePopup1() {
    document.getElementById('desktop-card').style.width = '480px';
}
```

```css
#desktop-card{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="togglePopup1()">Aperte Aqui</button>

<div id="desktop-card">Teste</div>
```

Obs: utilizei duas propriedades `transition`, a `transition-delay` que especifica o tempo para que a animação comece e a `transition-duration` que especifica o tempo de duração da animação.

Existe outras propriedades que você pode utilizar. [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) você pode ler e ver mais exemplos.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, mas só complementando, caso ele queira essa mudança aconteça apenas nesse caso ele poderia criar uma classe especifica que aumenta o `width` e também contenhas essas propriedades da `transition` e ao clicar ela seria adicionada a classe ao elemento. Evitando futuros efeitos colaterais.

Comment: Mas se bem que é um `id`, então dificilmente terá um efeito colateral. Então considerem o comentário acima apenas como didático kk

Answer (score 0):

Vitor, vllw mano.

Consegui aqui, na madruga tava com tanto sono que nem lembrei que poderia usar com CSS.

Porém, não funcionou para por exemplo

```
document.getElementById('desktop-card').style.display = 'block';
```

No caso da Div #desktop-card aparecer suave também.

Comment: não consegui entender direito, você quer aplicar o efeito de transição na div ao mesmo tempo que aplicar o display block no id desktop-card?